# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I know this error looks so familiar, and there may be many questions on the same topic. But, really this is a new question

I wrote a python 3 program in google cloud functions, with cloud pub/sub as the trigger and previously in July I executed this cloud function. It worked perfectly. Even now it's working. But, testing is throwing some error. Below is the image for your reference. I repeat this is an error in Google Cloud Function, not in python 3
[image]

Comment: I just tried running the basic Pub/Sub code, the one that comes by default in the Google Cloud Console, in the Testing tab and it worked just fine. Could you provide more information about the code you are running?

Comment: Well! Actually I donno how to add my code in comments? And moreover, function execution is fine, but i am assuming you didn't text with json format, like how i did earlier. Only testing is where I am having problem @pessolato

Comment: You can edit your question to provide more information. During my tests I specified the same properties you presented on your screenshot (data and temperature) with the same values, however it still worked correctly, with the output being "OK". I believe there might be an issue with the testing tab not sending an expected parameter to your function, but to be sure I would need to take a look at the code that is receiving these parameters.